# Detailed explanation of 'git remote show'

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-remote, remote-branch

I honestly cannot find any detailed documentation of the output of `git remote show` (certainly not on the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html))

In particular, a clear, exact explanation of the `Local` sections would be appreciated.

An example of what I find confusing:

Here I have two remotes, *klas* and *origin* and the output they produce:

```
> git remote show klas
* remote klas
  Fetch URL: ..\klasrepo
  Push  URL: ..\klasrepo
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    experiment  tracked
    feature     tracked
    master      tracked
    pu          tracked
    stashbranch tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    pu merges with remote pu
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    experiment pushes to experiment (fast-forwardable)
    feature    pushes to feature    (fast-forwardable)
    master     pushes to master     (fast-forwardable)
    pu         pushes to pu         (up to date)
> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: C:/Temp/git/.\barerepo.git
  Push  URL: C:/Temp/git/.\barerepo.git
  HEAD branch: experiment
  Remote branches:
    experiment tracked
    master     tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    experiment  merges with remote experiment
    master     rebases onto remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    experiment pushes to experiment (up to date)
    master     pushes to master     (fast-forwardable)
```

Notice that *experiment* and *master* are listed under **both** `local refs configured for 'git push'`. What does that mean? I have configured *master* and *experiment* to track *origin/master* and *origin/experiment* respectively (and *pu* to track *klas/pu*).

My local *feature* branch is not set up to track anything, but is still listed under `local refs configured for 'git push'` (the only connection seems to be the identical name, another non-tracking branch, *foo*, is not mentioned). `git push` while on *feature* gives `fatal: The current branch feature has no upstream branch.` - hardly "fast-forwardable".

It seems that the criteria for a local branch being listed under `local refs configured for 'git push'` is that there happens to exist a remote branch with the same name??

For reference:

```
> git branch -vva
  experiment                0cf7b2a [origin/experiment] added rand content 82 to .\rand_content.txt
* feature                   4b25f46 added rand content 62 to bar.txt
  foo                       40aee50 added rand content 17 to .\rand_content.txt
  master                    4b25f46 [origin/master] added rand content 62 to bar.txt
  pu                        44ad10b [klas/pu] added rand content 51 to doo.txt
  remotes/klas/experiment   1f4e89b app
  remotes/klas/feature      884e953 added rand content 80 to bar.txt
  remotes/klas/master       57877c1 added in tobias repo
  remotes/klas/pu           44ad10b added rand content 51 to doo.txt
  remotes/klas/stashbranch  8678cf0 added rand content 44 to .\rand_content.txt
  remotes/origin/HEAD       -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/experiment 0cf7b2a added rand content 82 to .\rand_content.txt
  remotes/origin/master     4b25f46 added rand content 62 to bar.txt
> git config --list --local | select-string 'branch|remote'
remote.origin.url=C:/Temp/git/.\barerepo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master.rebase=true
remote.klas.url=..\klasrepo
remote.klas.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/klas/*
branch.experiment.remote=origin
branch.experiment.merge=refs/heads/experiment
branch.pu.remote=klas
branch.pu.merge=refs/heads/pu
> git --version
git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Git 1.8.1.

Skimming the Git source code (specifically `remote.c` and `builtin/remote.c`), the list under "Local refs configured for 'git push'" is calculated as follows:

1. collect configured push refspecs:

   - read `.git/remotes/<remotename>` (an obsolete config file; see `git help repository-layout`)
   - read `.git/branches/<branchname>` (another obsolete config file)
   - examine the `remote.<remotename>.push` config item
2. if step #1 didn't find anything, use `:` as the only push refspec
3. find all {local, remote} branch combinations that matched the collected push refspecs

Note that the above algorithm doesn't pay attention to `branch.<branchname>.remote`, `branch.<branchname>.merge`, or `push.default`.

Under typical usage patterns, step #1 in the above algorithm will never find any configured refspecs so `:` will be used.  That refspec is a simple matching refspec, so with typical usage `git remote show <remotename>` will always print `<branchname> pushes to <branchname>` if there is a branch named `<branchname>` in both the local and remote repositories.